# how to interrupt(ctrl+c) the program in emacs shell(M-X shell)

Tags: emacs

When I was in shell mode, the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will be interpreted as the 'C-x'.

I have no idea about what can I do to interrupt the running program in emacs shell. 
I'm a novice in emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type it twice: <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> ...............